# IN clause for dates LinQ C#

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Good afternoon! I have a LINQ query:

```
results = from a in uow.Query<SomeTable>()
          where SomeDateField = somedate
          select a;
```

Now I should use IN clause for the some dates.
How can I do something like this in LINQ?

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDateField IN ('2021-08-30','2021-09-03','2021-08-16')
```

This is not a condition between two dates, namely IN clause for few dates

Comment: You can define a list of dates, then use `Contains` Linq extension

Comment: But Contains is for string?  DateTime does not consist Contains. I need this for datetime data type, not for strings

Comment: Mentioned `Contains` for `IEnumerable`